# the solution of linear combination with integer variables = fixed value

Tags: python, numpy

I plan to use python for the solution of next task.
There is an equation:

> E=(n[1])*W[1]+ (n[2])*W[2]+..+ (n[N])*W[N]. The W[i],

E are known and are fixed values,
n[i] are integer variables.
I need to find all combinations of n[i] and write them.
Howe can I do it using numpy python?

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far.
Always remember to provide a MCVE whenever you ask a question.
Ref https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a [Diophantine equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation).

There is no support for this in numpy/scipy and the usual suspect [Integer-programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) (which can be used to solve this) is also not available within scipy!

The general case is NP-hard!

Comment: I was trying to solve it with the writing explicitly “for in range(n[i]):”, but in this case it is more than 100 “for” and python shows the mistake (many identifications).

Comment: I note that there is a variant where n[I] and W[I], E can be float! Maybe in this case, is it simpler?

Comment: Yes, the continuous case (only variables to optimize matter; the remaining stuff can be discrete) is in P and can be solved by simple algorithms. E.g. numpy's linalg.solve in some cases (yours i suppose), or scipy's lsq_linear in general.